# PHP Glob all directories where some file does not exists

Tags: php, glob

I have directory that contains all projects:
/projects/{project name}

Some projects contains checksum file (checksum.chk).

I can get all directories that contains checksum file with glob:

```
glob('/projects/*/checksum.chk')
```

Now I need list of all project that does **NOT** contains checksum file. Simply negating file name doesn't work.

```
glob('/projects/*/!(checksum.chk)') // doesn't work
```

This can be done with iterators or similar, but im looking for glob() solution if possible.